# Arduino mini 3.3v mosfet driver for a pid heater

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I'm in the process of making an "all in one board" Arduino PID heater.

So far I've come up with this really simple design: [image]

But im quite new to electonics in general as you can see, and i'm having an hard time figuring out an actual 3.3v mosfet driver.

Any toughts? Did I do something orribly wrong?

Comment: Why is there an optoisolator when it is not used for isolation?

Comment: flip Q2 so that the gate is on left side ... draw R9 in horizontal orientation ... align U3 pin4, R9 and Q2 gate for a neater schematic diagram

Comment: --flip Q2 so that the gate is on left side ... draw R9 in horizontal orientation ... align U3 pin4, R9 and Q2 gate for a neater schematic diagram-- Thanks for the tips! As for the electricals? are we good?